# how do I set the data location with SqlServerCE without naming the sdf?

Tags: c#, deployment, entity-framework-5, connection-string, sql-server-ce-4

I'm using Sql Server Compact Edition v4 with EntityFramework v5. I pass the name of the sdf file into the constructor of my various DbContext inheritors. It works fine but always creates the files in ./App_Data. On my deployed server I want it to create the files in ../../data. Can I specify that data directory as part of the connection factory settings in the web.config? Or if I use a connection string, can I specify some kind of wildcard for the filename itself so that it continues to use the runtime-generated value passed to the DbContext constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate - [EF 5 + SQL CE 4: How to specify custom location for database file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12490190/1012641)

Comment: That example is not ideal because it uses CE-specific code. SQL CE is not my long-term solution; it's an intermediate hack that I hope will last until my host solution can support LocalDb.