# Set Additional Parameters in the entityFramework | defaultConnectionFactory for SqlServerCe.3.5

Tags: entity-framework-6, sql-server-ce

How do you set the additional parameters in app.config to reflect the directory where you want to the database to be created?  This posting "[EF 5 + SQL Server CE 4: How to specify custom location for database file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490190/ef-5-sql-ce-4-how-to-specify-custom-location-for-database-file)" does it programmatically, but I want to set the parameters in the .config file.

This is what I tried to do, but failed to get it work:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
        <parameter value="" />
        <parameter value="C:\\Users\\ericq\\Documents\\Data" />
    </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

Even tried:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
        <parameter value="data source=C:\\Users\\ericq\\Documents\\Data" />
    </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

and:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
        <parameter value="data source=C:\Users\ericq\Documents\Data" />
    </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

And, can't find any examples on MSDN "[SqlCeConnectionFactory Constructor (String, String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696324(v=vs.113).aspxs)"

So I'm assuming you need three parameters to make this work, but my format is not working according to LINQPad5 as I try to use it to figure out how to get this to work:

> ArgumentException Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 43.

The code I'm using:

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    Blog mMenu = (from p in db.Blogs where p.Name.Equals("Eric Miller") select p).FirstOrDefault();

    if (mMenu == null)
    {
        // Create and save a new Blog
        var name = "Eric Miller";
        var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
        db.Blogs.Add(blog);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Display all Blogs from the database
    var query = from b in db.Blogs
                orderby b.Name
                select b;

    Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
}
```

And the exception is triggering when I do this:

```
Blog mMenu = (from p in db.Blogs where p.Name.Equals("Eric Miller") select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

LINQPad5 App.config (Let me type it it:)

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
        <parameter value="" />
        <parameter value="C:\\Users\\ericq\\Documents\\Data" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.Legacy.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.Legacy" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 3.5" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Thanks!...

Answer (score 0):

Just add a connectionString to your config with the same name as your context:

```
<connectionStrings>  
  <add name="BloggingContext"   
   providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"   
   connectionString="data source=C:\data\eric.sdf;" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks ErikEJ, In summary, I wanted to use the defaultConnectionFactory for the main database and connectionStrings for others, but it looks like this is the only way to move databases around right?